# MapQuest add text in flag icon

Tags: mapquest

I have the following code and I want to add different text in each of the icons. Example for the location "Quebec" it should be entered "08h00" for "Beaupre" .. "15h00" etc..

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://api.mqcdn.com/sdk/mapquest-js/v1.3.2/mapquest.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://api.mqcdn.com/sdk/mapquest-js/v1.3.2/mapquest.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {
        L.mapquest.key = '';

        // Geocode three locations, then call the createMap callback
        L.mapquest.geocoding().geocode(['Quebec,Qc', 'Beaupre,Qc', 'Montmagny,Qc'], createMap);

        function createMap(error, response) {
          // Initialize the Map
          var map = L.mapquest.map('map', {
            layers: L.mapquest.tileLayer('map'),
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 12
          });

          // Generate the feature group containing markers from the geocoded locations
          var featureGroup = generateMarkersFeatureGroup(response);

          // Add markers to the map and zoom to the features
          featureGroup.addTo(map);
          map.fitBounds(featureGroup.getBounds());
        }

        function generateMarkersFeatureGroup(response) {
          var group = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
            var location = response.results[i].locations[0];
            var locationLatLng = location.latLng;

            // Create a marker for each location
            var marker = L.marker(locationLatLng, {icon: L.mapquest.icons.flag()})
                           
              .bindPopup(location.adminArea5 + ', ' + location.adminArea3);

            group.push(marker);
          }
          return L.featureGroup(group);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body style="border: 0; margin: 0;">
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 530px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Could anyone help me please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the symbol for the flag like icon: L.mapquest.icons.flag({symbol:"08h00"})

More details here: https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/mapquest-js/v1.3/l-mapquest-icons/